# Dependencies downloader for Android OS

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, dependency-management

I am taking care of my parents (by the Covid situation) in a place without Internet, not even mobile connectivity. I'm learning Android development and Gradle is requesting an Internet connection to download the dependencies on Android Studio. I only have a desktop computer (without internet), running Linux and a smartphone with Android. I can get Internet on my phone, traveling 20 km to the nearest city without my own car. Is there any tool or mechanism with which I can export the Android project's dependencies to my phone and, after that, connect to the Internet in the city and download the libraries to work with Gradle cache afterwards? I have done something like that before, but from my company with Sonatype Nexus. My PC without having an Internet connection, only connected to the LAN, sets as dependencies the local Maven repositories published in the Nexus, if it do not have the dependencies on the cache, it connect to the Internet and download the library later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the latest Android Gradle plugin and Google Maven dependencies in your mobile from the URL https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclsrc=aw.ds#downloads and then you can use it to build your projects offline.

Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline to configure android studio to work without network connection.